# UcanaccessSQLException: Unexpected page type 1

Tags: java, sql, ucanaccess

I'm getting this error when trying to update records in my database from within a java servlet/jsp page:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: Unexpected page type 1
>   (Db=M0MPM.mdb;Table=logbook;Index=contestId)

But I'm only getting it on one record, out of about 50 updates. I do not see anything special with this record, but I've seen the error before on different records with various updates, and it always seem to be in records near the beginning of the table (i.e. the oldest). The database is about 6500 records and growing slowly.

In this case the sql statement:

```
Update [logbook] set qslr = '07.09.2015'
where callsign='PA3BHF'
  and rfband='15M'
  and ldate='23.06.2013'
  and(isNull(qslr) or qslr ='')
```

I've used this `update` statement hundreds of times without a problem before moving to UcanAccess.

The statement also works fine when I execute it directly in the MS Access windows tool (straight copy and paste of the above Update).

Is this a UcanAccess bug, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried opening the database in Access and doing a "Compact and Repair Database" operation to rebuild the database file?

Comment: That may have done the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The first line of defense against errors like this is to open the database in Access and do a "Compact and Repair Database" operation to rebuild the database file. That removes unused database objects and fixes inconsistencies between the metadata and the actual data.